# How to model asynchronous callback in functional reactive programming?

Tags: rxjs, functional-programming, frp

As I understand, in FRP (Functional Reactive Programming), we model the system as a component which receives some input signals and generates some output signals:

```
                ,------------.
--- input1$ --> |            | -- output1$ -->
                |   System   | -- output2$ -->
--- input2$ --> |            | -- output3$ -->
                `------------'
```

In this way, if we have multiple subsystems, we can plump them together as long as we can provide operators that can pipe inputs and outputs.

Now, I'm building an app, which processes video frames asynchronously. The actual processing logic is abstracted and can be provided as an argument. In non-FRP way of thinking, I can construct the app as

```js
new App(async (frame) => {
    return await processFrame(frame)
})
```

The `App` is responsible for establishing communication with underlying video pipeline and repeatedly get video frames and then pass that frame to the given callback, and once the callback resolves,`App` sends back the processed frame.

Now I want to model the `App` in a FRP way so I can flexibly design the frame processing.

```js
const processedFrameSubject = new Subject()
const { frame$ } = createApp(processedFrameSubject)
frame$.pipe(
    map(toRGB),
    mergeMap(processRGBFrame),
    map(toYUV)
).subscribe(processedFrameSubject)
```

The benefit is that it enables the consumer of `createApp` to define the processing pipeline declaratively.

However, in `createApp`, given a `processedFrame`, I need to reason about which `frame` it is related to. Since `frame$` and `processedFrameSubject` is now separated, it's really hard for `createApp` to reason about which `frame` a `processedFrame` is related to, which was quite easy in non-FRP implementation because the `frame` and `processedFrame` were in same closure.

Comment: While I don't have the answer now, this is a super well asked question. I will review tomorrow.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `createApp`, please? Also it seems backwards. Why does it take `processedFrameSubject` as the input and return the  `frame$`?

Comment: @Bergi https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lhtuol?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts I hope this link may help you understand the problem.

Comment: @NandinBorjigin I don't quite understand what `registerVideoFrameHandler` does, but it doesn't seem to fit in a FRP model. If you gave the caller a way to handle this as a signal of frames, they could drop or duplicate frames?! olivarra1's answer is spot on, especially with the `processFrame`/`projectFn` still being passed to `createApp` and doing simple piping, instead of the caller having to tie the knot around the app using `subscribe()`.

Comment: @Bergi, `registerVideoFrameHandler` is not under my control and I must depend on it. It accepts a callback as frame handler, and periodically calls the handler with raw frames, expecting the handler to return a promise of processed frame.

Answer (score 1):

In functional reactive programming, you would avoid using side effects as much as possible, this means avoiding `.subscribe(`, `tap(() => subject.next())`, etc. With FRP, your state is declared on how it works and how it's wired up, but it doesn't execute until someone needs it and performs the side effect.

So I think that the following API would still be considered FRP:

```js
function createApp(
  processFrame: (frame: Frame) => Observable<ProcessedFrame>
): Observable<void>

const app$ = createApp(frame => of(frame).pipe(
  map(toRGB),
  mergeMap(processRGBFrame),
  map(toYUV)
));

// `app$` is an Observable that can be consumed by composing it to other
// observables, or by "executing the side effect" by .subscribe() on it

// possible implementation of createApp for this API
function createApp(
  processFrame: (frame: Frame) => Observable<ProcessedFrame>
) {
  return new Observable<void>(() => {
    const stopVideoHandler = registerVideoFrameHandler(
      (frame: Frame) => firstValueFrom(processFrame(frame))
    );

    return () => {
      // teardown
      stopVideoHandler()
    }
  });
}
```

Something worth noting is that `createApp` is returning a `new Observable`. Inside `new Observable(` we can escape from FRP because it's the only way we can integrate with external parties, and all the side effects we have written won't be called until someone `.subscribe()`s to the observable.

This API is simple and would still be FRP, but it has one limitation: the `processFrame` callback can only process frames independently from others.

If you need an API that supports that, then you need to expose the `frames$`, but again, this is a project function for `createApp`:

```js
function createApp(
  projectFn: (frame$: Observable<Frame>) => Observable<ProcessedFrame>
): Observable<void>

const app$ = createApp(frame$ => frame$.pipe(
  map(toRGB),
  mergeMap(processRGBFrame),
  map(toYUV)
));

// possible declaration of createApp
function createApp(
  projectFn: (frame$: Observable<Frame>) => Observable<ProcessedFrame>
) {
  return new Observable<void>(() => {
    const frame$ = new Subject<Frame>;
    const processedFrame$ = connectable(frame$.pipe(projectFn));
    const processedSub = processedFrame$.connect();

    const stopVideoHandler = registerVideoFrameHandler(
      (frame: Frame) => {
        // We need to create the promise _before_ we send in the next `frame$`,  in case it's processed synchronously
        const resultFrame = firstValueFrom(processedFrame$);

        frame$.next(frame);

        return resultFrame;
      })
    );

    return () => {
      // teardown
      stopVideoHandler()
      processedSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  });
}
```

I'm guessing here `registerVideoFrameHandler` will call the function one-by-one without overlap? If there's overlap then you'd need to track the frame number in some way, if the SDK doesn't give you any option, then try something like:

```js
// Assuming `projectFn` will emit frames in order. If not, then the API
// should change to be able to match them
const processedFrame$ = connectable(frame$.pipe(
  projectFn,
  map((result, index) => ({ result, index }))
));
const processedSub = processedFrame$.connect();

let frameIdx = 0;
const stopVideoHandler = registerVideoFrameHandler(
  (frame: Frame) => {
    const thisIdx = frameIdx;
    frameIdx++;

    const resultFrame = firstValueFrom(processedFrame$.pipe(
      filter(({ index }) => index === thisIdx),
      map(({ result }) => result)
    ));

    frame$.next(frame);

    return resultFrame;
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @olivarra1. I came up with similar approach as well. IMO, if we pass `projectFn` into `createApp`, it could be just a function from `Frame` to `Promise<ProcessedFrame>` and the frame index synchronization would be much easier to maintain. However, what I really want to achieve is to be able to define the frame processing pipeline after calling `createApp` -- this is why I exposed `frame$`. That being said, my intention to "define the pipeline after calling `createApp`" may not be a valid one though.